# How to set set return date asper onward date in ngx-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular5, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

In my website I am using Ngx-bootstarp date picker .i am using datepicker for onward and return date like (flight bokking site's datepicker).

when i am choosing any date in onward datepicker it should come same date with month in return date picker.In my case dates are working fine for return date picker when i am choosing the date from onward date picker but month is not coming as per onward date.

below i am showing the code for datepicker:
1.I have imported the date picker

```
 import { BsDaterangepickerDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
```

2.Now i am declaring two variable for two date picker(onward,return):

```
minDate: Date;
  minDate1: Date;
```

3.setting the configuration for current date inside constructor.

```
this.datePickerConfig=Object.assign({},{showWeekNumbers:false,dateInputFormat:"DD-MMM-YYYY"});
          this.minDate = new Date();  
          this.minDate1=new Date();    
          this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate());
          this.minDate1.setDate(this.minDate1.getDate());
          this.count=0;
   }
```

4.I am calling this function inside my return date picker html inpur field.

```
getReturnDate(){
      console.log(this.minDate1);
      this.count++;
      if($('#JourneyDate').val()){
      let tempDate = $('#JourneyDate').val();
      let parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(""+tempDate));
      this.minDate1.setDate(parsedDate.getDate());
      console.log(this.minDate1);
      if(this.count==1){
        this.getReturnDate();
      }
      }
      else{
      this.minDate1=new Date(); 
      this.minDate1.setDate(this.minDate1.getDate());
      }



    }
```

6.below I am giving the html code.
onward date picker field:

```
<input id="JourneyDate" class="form-control getdate" type="text" #JourneyDatepicker="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" [minDate]="minDate"
                             [(ngModel)]="model.onwardDate" name="JourneyDate"  placeholder="Journey date" autocomplete="off" readonly/>
```

return date picker field which calling the above function getReturnDate():

```
<input id="ReturnDate"  class="form-control getdate" type="text" #returndatepicker="bsDatepicker" 
                             bsDatepicker  [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" [minDate]="minDate1" (click)="getReturnDate()"
                             [(ngModel)]="model.returnDate" name="ReturnDate" autocomplete="off"  readonly (bsValueChange)="onReturnValueChange($event)"/>
```

below I am adding an image of that:
[In this image 1st field is onward date and the second one is return date as you can see it's taking the date as per onward but the month is different.

hope you can help me out with the problem. Thank you.